# Handling the browser back button in a multi-step form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the user goes to the next step in my 3 part form, the url doesn't change because I'm just changing state. The problem is they can't go back and modify the form using the browser button. After spending all afternoon trying to fix this, here's the closest I got:

```
  onBackButtonEvent = (e) => {
    console.log('handling back button press', e)
    if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.onpopstate = this.onBackButtonEvent();
  }
```

Comment: This isn't something worth your time re-inventing.  Check out React-Router.

Comment: Why do you don't use hashes in your url and check these by using `location.hash`? Or use the `react-router`.

Comment: @gravityplanx Sometimes the solution isn't to use a library. Libraries take up memory and can cause bad performance especially a library as large as React Router.

Answer (score 1):

Like the commenter noted above, your best bet will be to render your form pages as individual components, and delegate the concerns of browser navigation to React-Router. You can read more about it at the [React Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy). Below, I've shown some basic things you can add to your app, after re-factoring the form into some components.

```
// index.js (or file where you add your App to dom)
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);


// App.js
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

// render
<Route exact path="/form/page1" render={(props) => (
  <FormPage1
    {...props}
    necessaryProp={this.state.necessaryProp}
    handleSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit} />
)} />

<Route exact path="/form/page2" render={(props) => (
  <FormPage2
    {...props}
    necessaryProp={this.state.necessaryProp}
    handleSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit} />
)} />
```

You could play around with validations using your page component's componentDidMount or componentWillMount lifecycle events...

To change pages, you can either submit the form, and handle it based on the page # that did submit. Another approach is to use `<Link to="/form/page2" />` inside of the page components. Finally, a third approach you could use is to have an onClick handler on a button perform your validation. If the form is valid, use `props.history.push('/form/page2')` to redirect programatically... The implementation details are up to you!

The key is React Router abstracts the browser navigation concern, handling cross-browser effects, and is what you're looking for.

Comment: When using React Router in this way, what is a good pattern for handling state for the multi pages?

My app has confirm-and-persist at the end of the wizard.  I can keep state in <FormTopLevel> and pass down to <FormPage1>, <FormPage2>, etc. using state to render one or the other - but then browser history doesn't work.  So, React Router seems like the right solution... but then I see three options: a) persist after each step, b) lift the multi page state all the way up to App, since that's where the routes are, or c) use something like Redux.

Is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

Comment: I'd recommend using Redux to handle storing the state. Redux would essentially do 'b' and 'c' for you, and would do 'a' as well if implemented with [controlled form components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).  `<FormPage1>`, and `<FormPage2>` etc would have logic in the components to validate the parts of the state which they represent. It's often helpful to store the form state in a different reducer--separate from your permanent data model--until the final submit, so back/forward navigation doesn't trip you up.